# Build Chainlink Node from Source, not sure how to reference GCP SQL instance

Tags: chainlink

I've recently built a chainlink node from source (no Docker). When trying to start the node, it's still looking for a local postgresql so I receive this error:

`You must set DATABASE_URL env variable. HINT: If you are running this to set up your local test database, try DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432/chainlink_test?sslmode=disable logger=1.4.1@8843bef`

This happens even when I have the environmental variable set to:
`DATABASE_URL=postgresql://linkster:password@10.5.0.3:5432/link`

Also I have this set in a .env where I'm trying to start the node.

I know the GCP SQL instance, database and user exists since I can log in successfully using this:
`PGPASSWORD=password psql -h 10.5.0.3 -p 5432 -d "link" -U "linkster"`

Looking through the menu, I don't see a way to reference an external database. Did I miss something? Or is there a directory I need to have the .env file?

Comment: can you try manually setting/exporting your node env vars instead of having them all in a .env file? eg export DATABASE_URL='xyz', then try start your node?

Answer (score 1):

looking at the node source code, .env files are not natively supported. The only reason they work with running a node through docker, is because docker can take a [--env-file parameter](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/), which it then uses to create the environment variables for the container.

When running from source, you should manually set all environment variables in the environment that you're in. eg:

```
export DATABASE_URL=postgresql://linkster:password@10.5.0.3:5432/link
```